# Elastic Beanstalk AMI Image giving error of 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running elastic Beanstalk with node js.
But since today, I started to get this error, making me imposible to deploy my application.
Not sure how to change this, as I'm using the latest version `Node.js version 4.14.1`

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... 
The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found error: skipping http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm - transfer failed Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm. command atk in .ebextensions/02_chromiumpackages.config failed. 
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Comment: Have you checked ` /var/log/eb-activity.log `?

Comment: Yes and that's the error I get. The one I posted

Comment: If you manually check the `atk` link (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm) you see it does not exist. The current version is `atk-2.28.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`, not the one you are trying to install.

Comment: Yeap, that's right. But I don't know which AMI am using. As I used the defaults version of AWS. How can I change this?

Comment: Maybe have to refresh repos before trying to install the packages?

Comment: I don't install any packages. Just using the default template. So not sure how that's done.

Comment: Where does `.ebextensions/02_chromiumpackages.config` is coming form? `.ebextensions` is a folder you put in your deployment package.

Comment: @Marcin I got it, but which will the new package be?

Comment: Do you explicitly specify fixed version? Do you use `atk: []` to install current one.?

Comment: Actually I do, as I need puppeteer, so I do a commands:
  atk:
    command: rpm -ivh --nodeps --replacepkgs http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.22.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
  at-spi2-atk:
http://chimmelb.blogspot.com/2018/11/using-puppeteer-in-aws-node.html

Comment: I will replace it with this one: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Have a try. Hopefully other packages are fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exact same issue this morning. 
Changing the ATK package version to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.28.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm resolve the issue for me.

But I still don't know why atk-2.28.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is no longer available.